# How to disable JIT compilation with HHVM?

Tags: php, xdebug, jit, hhvm

I'm working with `hhvm 3.6.1`--please exuse my limited understanding of the internals of HHVM and how it performs JIT.

I'm trying to suppress JIT compilation in HHVM and run the php in interpreted mode.   Right now I'm guessing you could set the warm  up request in your `php.ini` to some arbitrarily high number like:

```
 hhvm.eval.jit_warmup_requests = 1000
```

However, I'm looking to see if any one knows a setting like `jit_enabled=false`

The reason I'm doing this is I'm seeing wonky behavior running with xdebug enabled with remote debuging (seemingly random seg faults,  mismatched file to breakpoints) and want to factor the JIT out--if that makes any sense at all with how HHVM functions.

Comment: Have you tried `hhvm.jit = false`

Comment: That does not seem to work

Comment: @tlens I've also tried `hhvm.eval.jit = false` and this seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/INI-Settings claims that the INI form is indeed `hhvm.jit` -- not sure if that's accurate, but the command-line option is definitely `-v Eval.Jit=false`. (I'm curious how you are determining that the JIT is still enabled and the option didn't work?)

That said, xdebug is believed to work, and furthermore the team at FB (and nearly every usage, inside FB and out) all run with the JIT enabled. Believe it or not, that's actually likely to be much *better* supported than the interpreter at this point.

If you're running into problems with xdebug, you should file an issue: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues

Comment: I'm trying to gather as much info as I can before submitting the bug.  I must be misunderstanding how to detect when JIT is running or not.  Currently, I'm watching the log, making 11 requests and on the twelve through fifteenth requests observing `[] Finished singleJitRequest 1` , `[] Finished singleJitRequest 2` ...   I might falsely be assuming this means JIT is going on.  This happens regardless of whether I set `hhvm.jit=false`  or `hhvm.eval.jit=false` or set an arbitratirly high number of warm-up requests.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for hours too.

To disable JIT, you should lookup "hhvm.jit = 1" in server.ini, not php.ini.